# Is there an automatic way to initialize private variables - instead of accepting them as constructor arguments?

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++

I am trying to use the constructor to initialize a private variable but when looking at the code this seems annoying and repeatitive.

```
class Parent
{
public:
    Parent(string _name, string _eyecolor, string _skincolor, string _gender, int _age)
    {
        // Cluttered
        _name = name;
        _eyecolor = eyecolor;
        _skincolor = skincolor;
        _gender = gender;
        _age = age;
    }
private:
    string name, eyecolor, skincolor, gender;
    int age;
};
```

Comment: That assigns to them rather than initializing them (they are default-initialized before the assignment).

Comment: exactly. if you want to initialize them, use the initializer list. also, your assignments are backwards.

Comment: Apart from the errors (in both your question, and in the code) that others have pointed out, where is the repetition?   There is no duplication of code, no variable or object being assigned more than once.   Yes, there are five (incorrect) assignments, but they are not replicated.

Answer (score 1):

No there's not a way to automatically initialize member variables. If you think about it, that would be terrible if there was. How would the compiler know what you wanted to initialize the variables with?

As others said, you're not actually initializing the members. You aren't even assigning anything to them. You're assigning the member variables to the constructor's arguments here. Look up the syntax for initializing member variables in a constructor. It could be something like this, buy maybe formatted however you like it (I'm on a tablet so I can't format it too well).

```
class Parent { 
public: 
    Parent(string _name, string _eyecolor, string _skincolor, string _gender, int _age) 
        : name{ _name },  eyecolor{ _eyecolor },  skincolor{ _skincolor }, gender{ _gender }, age{ _age } 
    {
    }
private: 
    string name, eyecolor, skincolor, gender; 
    int age;
};
```

If you mean you want to initialize them with some (defined) value without passing arguments, you can initialize them with a default constructor, essentially the same way I did above.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a default constructor that makes use of another constructor you defined in C++11:

```
class Parent
{
public:
    Parent() :
        Parent("Richard", "Pink", "Green", "Male", 777)
    {}

    Parent(string _name, string _eyecolor, string _skincolor, string _gender, int _age)
    {
        // Cluttered
        _name = name;
        _eyecolor = eyecolor;
        _skincolor = skincolor;
        _gender = gender;
        _age = age;
    }
private:
    string name, eyecolor, skincolor, gender;
    int age;
};
```

If your compiler doesn't support this feature you can always do it manually:

```
class Parent
{
public:
    Parent() :
        name("Richard"),
        eyecolor("Pink"),
        skincolor("Green"),
        gender("Male"),
        age(777)
    {}

    Parent(string _name, string _eyecolor, string _skincolor, string _gender, int _age)
    {
        // Cluttered
        _name = name;
        _eyecolor = eyecolor;
        _skincolor = skincolor;
        _gender = gender;
        _age = age;
    }
private:
    string name, eyecolor, skincolor, gender;
    int age;
};
```